# Bijection between graphs and natural integers.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Is there an explicit function $f$ (or an algorithm) that takes a finite graph to the natural numbers such that $f(G)=f(H) \iff G\simeq H$ 
(surjectivity is not necessary, but would be great ;))

e.g. for small graphs $f$ could look like:

$f(K_0)=1$

$f(K_1)=2$

$f(\overline{K_2})=3,f(K_2)=4$

$f(\overline{K_3})=5,f(K_2\cup K_1)=6,f(P_3)=7,f(K_3)=8$

etc.

Comment: May we assume labeled graphs?  Otherwise your function has to solve the graph isomorphism problem.

Comment: Sure. You can't really write a single equation that describes it, but it's not so hard to write a program that does this.

Comment: @hardmath Solving the graph isomorphism problem is straightforward - solving it quickly is what's difficult.

Comment: (Note: the program I'm thinking of is horribly inefficient. I never claimed it would finish in a reasonable amount of time.)

Comment: Oh true, if a simple function was known, the graph isomorphism problem wouldn't be so hard...

Comment: For a vertex-labeled graph, just read off the adjacency matrix as a binary integer (with $n^2$ digits).  For an unlabeled graph, let $f(G)$ be the minimum value of this over all $n!$ orderings of the vertices.

Comment: @mjqxxxx:  There is an ambiguity caused when the first vertex (of a labelled graph) has no edge since this results in all zero leading bits.  There are several ways to avoid this, perhaps the most obvious being to set the leading diagonal entry to 1, knowing that an adjacency matrix has only zeros on the diagonal (for a simple graph).

Comment: @hardmath: Can this be made into an isomorphsm?

Comment: @swami: The map as described, even inserting a leading one, fails to be surjective for many reasons.  Note that the lengths of these bit strings are $n^2$ for $n$ vertices, that the adjacency graph is always symmetric, and that other diagonal entries after the first would always contain zero.  Of course in principle the countability of finite graphs means an enumeration of them exists, but it would hardly resemble the above injective map.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. Consider first creating a table of all possible graphs and grouping isomorphic graphs together. Sort the table in some consistent way and assign increasing numbers to each set of isomorphic graphs. Note that there is no need to calculate such a table ahead of time. Once you need the corresponding number for a graph just calculate the table until you encounter said graph.

A way to get a ordering would be to consider each graph of the form
$(V,E)$.
Where $V = \{1, \ldots, n\} ≈\in \mathbb{Z}$
And where $E \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^2$.

One can simplify this to: $(V, E)$ with $V \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $E \in 2^{V^2}$. This gives an enumeration isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @mattsamuel yes, isomorphism classes ia what i meant.